# How to check if every month 13th is friday or not using only LocalDate?

Tags: java

I would like to check from 2019-01-01 to 2029-12-12 when 13th day of month is a friday using `LocalDate` only. How to convert `LocalDate.getDayOfMonth()` to `String` what says it is Monday/Tuesday/.../Saturday/Sunday?

```
    for (int i = 2019; i < 2030; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(i, j, 13);
            int dayOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth();


        }
    }
```

Comment: LocalDate has a method `getDayOfWeek` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `enum` `java.time.DayOfWeek` for checking if it is a friday:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2019; i < 2030; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(i, j, 13);
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();

            if (dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY) {
                System.out.println("Beware of bad luck in " 
                        + j + "/" + i + "…");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Beware of bad luck in 9/2019…
Beware of bad luck in 12/2019…
Beware of bad luck in 3/2020…
Beware of bad luck in 11/2020…
Beware of bad luck in 8/2021…
Beware of bad luck in 5/2022…
Beware of bad luck in 1/2023…
Beware of bad luck in 10/2023…
Beware of bad luck in 9/2024…
Beware of bad luck in 12/2024…
Beware of bad luck in 6/2025…
Beware of bad luck in 2/2026…
Beware of bad luck in 3/2026…
Beware of bad luck in 11/2026…
Beware of bad luck in 8/2027…
Beware of bad luck in 10/2028…
Beware of bad luck in 4/2029…
Beware of bad luck in 7/2029…
```

If you want to get the `String` representation of the `DayOfWeek`, you can do it like this:

```java
String weekday = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault());
```

In this example, the full name used in the system default `Locale` is chosen, which is `"Freitag"` in my `Locale`, but you can use `Locale.US` or another one instead.

Same applies to `java.time.Month`, see this new (but only slightly different) example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2019; i < 2030; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(i, j, 13);
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();

            // get the day of week as String (full name, US style)
            String weekday = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.US);
            // get the name of the Month as String (full name, US style)
            Month month = Month.of(j);

            if (dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY) {
                System.out.println("Beware of bad luck on " 
                        + weekday 
                        + " 13th, " 
                        + month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US) 
                        + " " 
                        + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to check every month between 1/1/2019 and 12/31/2030 you can do it in a single while loop instead of two for loops.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    //Set the local time to januray 13th 2019
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2019,Month.JANUARY,13,0,0,0,0);
    while(ldt.getYear() < 2030) { //stop after 2030
      //check to see if the day of the week is a Friday
      if (ldt.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY) {
        System.out.println("Friday the 13th is on " + ldt);
      }
      ldt = ldt.plusMonths(1); //Add a month
    }
  }
```

And the output would look something like this:

```
Friday the 13th is on 2019-09-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2019-12-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2020-03-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2020-11-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2021-08-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2022-05-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2023-01-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2023-10-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2024-09-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2024-12-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2025-06-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2026-02-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2026-03-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2026-11-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2027-08-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2028-10-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2029-04-13T00:00
Friday the 13th is on 2029-07-13T00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)
  System.out.println(date.toString() + " is Friday 13th");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 2019; i < 2030; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(i, j, 13);
        System.out.println(date.getDayOfWeek());
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
WEDNESDAY
FRIDAY
MONDAY
THURSDAY
SATURDAY
TUESDAY
THURSDAY
```